# Can you create a chart without having a table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I am trying to create a chart that updates automatically when somebody clicks a drop down tab.

When you create a table it makes the spreadsheet look ugly and clunky.

I want to be able to have another page open where my charts update and am I able to get an overall view with charts from some single column drop down menus. Has anybody ever done this and how?

From this:

[image: Table image]

to this:

[image: Chart image]

Comment: 1. What do you mean by a chart for the type of data in your image?  Can you post a link to an image, or add a mockup? 2. The built-in charting functions are based on using a data array.  Can you clarify what you're thinking of as far as the data source?  It would be really useful to give an explicit example of what you want some sample data to look like, and what you want the chart of that data to look like.

Comment: Hey Fixer1234, I can imagine what I posted is hard to decipher as I don't really know what I am trying to say. I know in my head what I want but am struggling to figure out how to search for it. what I did is took a shot from what I have to what I want to have on a another tab. Think of it as an bunch of people inputting data and then having an 'at a glance" snapshot of that information updated.

Comment: The data can be on a different sheet than the chart.

Answer (score 3):

Data for a chart can be in the worksheet grid and/or in named formulas, although the latter is a fairly complex topic.

Typically the data for a chart is somewhere in a worksheet. That does not mean that the chart data has to be on the same sheet as the actual chart.

You can have the chart on a dashboard sheet and data in one or more data sheets.
On the dashboard sheet you can have controls like selection cells with drop-downs that the user manipulates.

In the sheet with the data you can then use formulas to react to the user selection and prepare the chart source range with the data that correlates to the user selection. This is the core principle of dynamic charts.

For example, in the data sheet you can have three columns of data: Apples, Bananas, Oranges. Next to that you have a column with a formula that pulls the values from one of these columns. That one column with the formula is the data source for the chart.

On the dashboard sheet the user has a drop down and can select either Apples or Bananas or Oranges. The formula in the data sheet then pulls the correct value into the column that is the data source for the chart, for example with an Index/Match formula.

The formula changes the data values in the cells that are the chart source, so as soon as the user changes the selection (on the dashboard sheet), the cell values on the data sheet change and the chart on the dashboard will update.

Dynamic charts can be very simple or very complex. It really depends on your scenario.

Comment: Would PowerPivot be another option?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Option for what? Power Pivot is about modelling the data and performing calculations. Pivot charts will create their underlying data as pivot tables in the worksheet.